# Проблемы кроссбразерности

Tags: javascript, safari

В Safari не работает, но работает в Google Chrome, Opera. Не могу понять в чем проблема. Можно с объяснением сказать в чем проблема?

```js
function time () {
    var deadline='2019-10-24 22:29:06';
    var t=Date.parse(deadline)-Date.parse(new Date());
    var seconds = Math.floor((t/1000) % 60);
    var minutes = Math.floor((t/1000/60) % 60);
    var hours = Math.floor((t/(1000*60*60)) % 24);
    if (hours === 0 & minutes === 0 & seconds === 0) {
        window.location.reload();
    }else {
        if (hours < 10) {
            hours = '0' + hours;
        }

        if (minutes < 10) {
            minutes = '0' + minutes;
        }

        if (seconds < 10) {
            seconds = '0' + seconds;
        }

       console.log(hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds);

        setTimeout(time, 1000);
    }
}
time ();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Формат времени

Поменяй `2019-10-24 22:29:06` на `2019-10-24T22:29:06`